# use a restful web service in windows phone 8.1

Tags: rest, windows-phone-8

Warm greetings.
I would like to know how I can use a restful web service(`http://192.168.10.113:8087/cisms/mobilews/`) which was developed using java, in my windows phone 8.1 application. I am using visual studio 2013 with c#.

**Update**: I have another issue with one of the GET methods in my web service(`http://192.168.10.152:8087/cisms/mobilews/login/userNameCheck?userName=supervisor`). When I created the following sample code based on the given URL, It threw another exception.

```
static string UserValidation()
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.10.113:8087/cisms/mobilews/login/userNameCheck?userName=supervisor") as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()  as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }

http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-c-sharp.html
```

The exception is given below

```
'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no
 extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

**NB:** I got this error only in Windows_Phone_application; not in Desktop_Application.

If anyone could help me further, that would be great

Thanks in advance
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) allows you to easily request web services. Or you could use [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/).

Comment: I have tried the httpwebrequest way, but there are few exceptions.

One of the web service method which I am using is GET; the url is follows...

http://192.168.10.152:8087/cisms/mobilews/login/userNameCheck?userName=supervisor

When I followed the below url, http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-c-sharp.html; It threw the following exception 

'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse'

If you could help me further, that would be great

Comment: I'm not in front of my work pc but maybe you could try something like that: `HttpWebResponse resp = ((await req.GetResponseAsync()) as HttpWebResponse)`

Comment: I have tried that , but got the same exception. I have noticed that this error come only in windows_phone_application, not in Desktop_application.

Comment: Try using sy httpClient.GetASync() instead of WebRequest

Comment: When time permits, can you show me a sample, Because I couldn't add System.Net.Http.dll is to my .net 4.5 application

Comment: You should use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient for Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 apps : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx

Comment: Whenever I try to add "Windows.Web.Http.dll", it gives me the following error - "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project"